# ANR in Canvas.native_drawBitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, native

I've been receiving the same ANR reports recently.
The ANR happens when app tries to draw some bitmaps (when rendering a GridView with ImageViews as elements).
I've did a lot of debugging and can now surely say that hangs don't depend neither on bitmap, nor on position where it's being drawn.

The heap is 50% free, images are no bigger than 400px^2
Grid elements doesn't have any custom layout - just simple ImageView.
Tested on HTC Desire (1 GHz CPU), Hero, emulators, etc.
The ANR continues **forever** so it's like some infinite loop is running while drawing bitmap.

What else can cause such a hang?

The report follows:

```
DALVIK THREADS:
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x40020ba0 self=0xddd0
  | sysTid=32366 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=-1345025972
  at android.graphics.Canvas.native_drawBitmap(Native Method)
  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1045)
  at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:323)
  at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:860)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How big are these Bitmaps? How many ImageViews are we talking here?  Could you post the layout you are trying to use? or some code that generates the layout? My suspicion is just that the Image is too big (dimension or dense) and it is hard to draw such images on slower phones. If they are all on the same screen it is quite possible it's heap squashing and growing.

Comment: @Greg, I've added details to question.

Comment: It could also be scaling? Like if you are saying setImageBitmap() a new BitmapDrawable is created on the UIThread. If the image is not prescaled to fit the dimensions of the ImageView, it will be scaled on the UIThread as well and that can take some time depending on the hardware (Memory heavy and CPU heavy too). Sorry if this sounds like a "Did you plug it in?" sort of answer, but without much context as to how the layout is configured I am not sure how to make sense of basically just a stacktrace.

Comment: @Greg, it really is scaled, but the problem is not that it takes **long**, but that it takes **forever**. Hundreds of same-size images are downscaled immediately in this ImageView.

Comment: You said you are getting this from ANR reports. Long is usually the reason as once the ANR fires, I don't think the main thread is allowed any CPU time unless the person says to wait (Which they usually don't). IF you have a gridview with 100's of imageviews .. well that's the problem. use View recycling or page. Again sort of generic answer because there is not much context given. Paste some code or a layout, a stack is pretty useless without context.

Comment: Add some code so we can see potential coding issues

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to pinpoint your problem without your code or at least a small sample. You probably need to load you images using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Also turning on [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) is very helpful for finding ANR errors.

```
public void onCreate() {
 if (DEVELOPER_MODE) {
     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
             .detectDiskReads()
             .detectDiskWrites()
             .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
             .penaltyLog()
             .build());
     StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
             .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
             .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
             .penaltyLog()
             .penaltyDeath()
             .build());
 }
 super.onCreate();
 }
```

Make sure to remove StrictMode before you release. It will cause a VerifyError on devices before api level 9.
It's a nice feature to use during development. It will cause your app to crash gracefully when ever you do something that might block the UI thread.